# In Android, how do you add an image to LinearLayout without stretching it vertically (across Y axis)?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-linearlayout

I want the image to stretch/shrink to fit horizontally but not vertically. Anyway of achieving this, preferably through xml, but dynamically will also do?

IT MUST BE FOR LINEARLAYOUT IS THE KEY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE 2: See update at the bottom for correct answer.

NOTE: Sorry, I misread the question and saw that you wanted this to stretch in one direction.  I'll amend my answer if I figure that one out but this will at least stop it from stretching at all.

You'll have to create a new drawable resource to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image" 
    android:tileMode="clamp" />
```

Just replace `your_image` with the name of your resource, save this in your drawables folder, and set this as the background.  This should draw the image in the top left of your linear layout and not repeat.

UPDATE: This will get the image to stretch horizontally, not vertically, and be aligned at the top of the linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image" 
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|clip_vertical|top"
    android:tileMode="disabled" />
```

Sorry for the initial mix-up.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the border change colors? (The black bars created above and below the image)

Comment: I haven't seen any sort of black bars showing up. Can you post a screen shot to clarify?

Comment: I created a separate question for this help end this comment string along with help you out for answering a separate question for additional points. [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372134/how-to-remove-black-bars-from-linearlayout-using-bitmap-as-background-in-android

Comment: Check the attached question for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `scaleType` attribuite on `ImageView`. Check out the possible values in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

A common use is to set `scaleType="centerCrop"`, which will maintain the image's aspect ratio, but scale such that the width and height of the resulting scale will be equal to or greater than your actual `ImageView` width and height.

If you want to change the aspect ratio, you can use `scaleType="fitXY"`.

Comment: I know how to with ImageView but I need it to work with LinearLayout.

Comment: You mean like the background of a LinearLayout?

Comment: Yeah. The background source is set to a draw able image.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to scale a background image. Try using a FrameLayout with an ImageView and a LinearLayout on top, rather than a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Set `layout_width` to `match_parent` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. Then set the [`scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) to `FIT_XY` (all for the `ImageView` itself, not the `LinearLayout`).

Comment: I know how to with ImageView but I need it to work with LinearLayout.