# How to remove black bars from LinearLayout using Bitmap as background in Android?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-linearlayout

![current layout] http://i50.tinypic.com/qqznzs.png

I am trying to get the blakc bars from the top and bottom of the layout to be white instead of black. I have tried changing the background color already.

DRAWABLE CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|center"
    android:src="@drawable/theblindgoat_logo"
    android:tileMode="disabled" >
</bitmap>
```

MAIN CODE:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/startup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

BTW I need the image to not stretch vertically, so changing that isn't a needed solution either.

Comment: Can you post the whole xml layout please ?

Comment: I did now. And it is not set to the drawable at the initial main but instead within the activity so it will only take effect after an animation takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those black bars are just the color of the background for the theme.  To get rid of them, you can change your bitmap drawable to be a layer list with a background color of white like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|center"
            android:src="@drawable/theblindgoat_logo"
            android:tileMode="disabled" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ditch that black color in two ways:

- Set background of your `LinearLayout` to white color and then add an
  `ImageView` inside with the desired image source

Or

- Set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` to your activity in
  **AndroidManifest.xml** and leave the rest as it is

Comment: Thanks for helping but without going into too much detail, I can't add an imageview to my linearlayout with messing up other layout items and the bottom solution didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: then simply go with my second option i.e. to set a light theme to your activity

Comment: That's what I was saying, the second solution didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background of the LinearLayout to the bitmap as such:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/startup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/theblindgoat_logo"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

That should stretch your image to fill the background.

Comment: I guess I should've been more specific but I need the image to stay without stretching. Thanks for helping.